# Image size decreases after modification of metadata i.e (EXIF,GPS,TIFF)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xcode7.3

I'm trying to modify the metadata of images but it seems that the file size of original image decreases considerably that annoying me too much. If the size of image is 6MB than it goes down to 3.2MB after modification. I know its strange but not impossible. Is there anyone to help me out in order to solve this issue. Your help will be appreciated.
Here is my code written in swift 2.0 and tool is Xcode 7.3.1 .

```
 func writeProperties(url:NSURL, override: Bool) -> NSURL?{
    guard let directory = url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent else { return nil }
    guard let base = url.URLByDeletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent else { return nil }
    guard let ext = url.pathExtension else { return nil }
    let newName = override ? url.lastPathComponent! : "\(base)_modified.\(ext)"
    let newPath = directory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(newName, isDirectory: false)
    print("writeProperties to \(newPath)")
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil) else { return nil }
    let imageType = CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource)!
    let data = NSMutableData()
    guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, imageType, 1, nil) else { return nil }
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(imageDestination, imageSource, 0, saveProperties)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)
    if let _ = try? data.writeToURL(newPath, options: NSDataWritingOptions.AtomicWrite) {
      let alert = NSAlert()
      alert.messageText = "Image Saved"
      alert.informativeText = "Image saved to \(newPath.path!)"
      alert.runModal()
      return newPath
    }
    return nil
  }
```